# cannot launch JavaFX web app for second time (relaunch) with Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, javafx

I have a problem with IE when I try to relaunch JavaFX app on web ( for the second call ).. this happens only in IE ..
the problem is that I get cert notifications twice but what I expect is one ..

a sample of that:
what I am doing is exiting from app ( when pressing the button )  ( see java code below ) and call launchit on JS ..

my html :

```
<html><head>

<script language="JavaScript" src="./web-files/dtjava.js"></script>

<script>





    function launchit(){

 dtjava.embed(
            {
                url : 'Simple_reLaunchJFX.jnlp',
                placeholder : 'javafx-app-placeholder',
                width : 800,
                height : 600,
                jnlp_content : 'PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4w..........pubHA+DQo='
            },
            {
                javafx : '2.2+'
            },
            {}
        );


    dtjava.addOnloadCallback(javafxEmbed);
    }
</script>

</head><body>
<h2>__</h2>


  <a href='#' onclick="launchit();">start JFX</a><br><hr><br>

  <br>

  <!-- Applet will be inserted here -->
  <div id='javafx-app-placeholder'></div>
</body></html>
```

Java:

```
package simple_relaunchjfx;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author maher
 */
public class Simple_reLaunchJFX extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage primaryStage) {
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'");


        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(btn);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();



        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                System.out.println("Hello World!");
                try {
                    primaryStage.close();
                    Platform.exit();
                    System.exit(0);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    System.err.println("error " + ex.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * The main() method is ignored in correctly deployed JavaFX application.
     * main() serves only as fallback in case the application can not be
     * launched through deployment artifacts, e.g., in IDEs with limited FX
     * support. NetBeans ignores main().
     *
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I solved it ..

I just create another holder (div) dynamically on run-time by calling

```
addElement(count);
```

and call

```
dtjava.addOnloadCallback(javafxEmbed);
```

javafxEmbed has reference to new id of holder div

that will cause multiple holders (div) @ the same time .. I tried to remove the previous holder .. but that doesnt solve the problem..with IE its showing 2 prompts ..

but that is not the end :) I just hide the previous div after creating new instance of JavaFX be calling

```
hidepreviousElement(count-1)
```

I include all methods in one :

```
function launchit(){
    count=count+1;

    addElement(count);
    dtjava.addOnloadCallback(javafxEmbed);
    hidepreviousElement(count-1);
    }
```

I know there are variant methods how to add/remove .. I just use what is considered to be compatible with common browsers IE/FF/Chrome..

```
<html><head>

<script language="JavaScript" src="./web-files/dtjava.js"></script>

<script>

var count=1;
   function javafxEmbed() {
        dtjava.embed(
            {
                url : 'Simple_reLaunchJFX_1_002.jnlp',
                placeholder : 'javafx-app-placeholder'+count,
                width : 800,
                height : 600,
                jnlp_content : 'PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0idXRmLTgiPz4NCjxqbmxwIHNwZWM9IjEuMCIgeG1sbnM6amZ4PSJodHRwOi8vamF2YWZ4LmNvbSIgaHJlZj0iU2ltcGxlX3JlTGF1bmNoSkZYXzFfMDAyLmpubHAiPg0KICA8aW5mb3JtYXRpb24+DQogICAgPHRpdGxlPlNpbXBsZV9yZUxhdW5jaEpGWF8xXzAwMjwvdGl0bGU+DQogICAgPHZlbmRvcj5tYWhlcjwvdmVuZG9yPg0KICAgIDxkZXNjcmlwdGlvbj5udWxsPC9kZXNjcmlwdGlvbj4NCiAgICA8b2ZmbGluZS1hbGxvd2VkLz4NCiAgPC9pbmZvcm1hdGlvbj4NCiAgPHJlc291cmNlcz4NCiAgICA8amZ4OmphdmFmeC1ydW50aW1lIHZlcnNpb249IjIuMisiIGhyZWY9Imh0dHA6Ly9qYXZhZGwuc3VuLmNvbS93ZWJhcHBzL2Rvd25sb2FkL0dldEZpbGUvamF2YWZ4LWxhdGVzdC93aW5kb3dzLWk1ODYvamF2YWZ4Mi5qbmxwIi8+DQogIDwvcmVzb3VyY2VzPg0KICA8cmVzb3VyY2VzPg0KICAgIDxqMnNlIHZlcnNpb249IjEuNisiIGhyZWY9Imh0dHA6Ly9qYXZhLnN1bi5jb20vcHJvZHVjdHMvYXV0b2RsL2oyc2UiLz4NCiAgICA8amFyIGhyZWY9IlNpbXBsZV9yZUxhdW5jaEpGWF8xXzAwMi5qYXIiIHNpemU9IjIwODQ5IiBkb3dubG9hZD0iZWFnZXIiIC8+DQogIDwvcmVzb3VyY2VzPg0KPHNlY3VyaXR5Pg0KICA8YWxsLXBlcm1pc3Npb25zLz4NCjwvc2VjdXJpdHk+DQogIDxhcHBsZXQtZGVzYyAgd2lkdGg9IjgwMCIgaGVpZ2h0PSI2MDAiIG1haW4tY2xhc3M9ImNvbS5qYXZhZngubWFpbi5Ob0phdmFGWEZhbGxiYWNrIiAgbmFtZT0iU2ltcGxlX3JlTGF1bmNoSkZYXzFfMDAyIiA+DQogICAgPHBhcmFtIG5hbWU9InJlcXVpcmVkRlhWZXJzaW9uIiB2YWx1ZT0iMi4yKyIvPg0KICA8L2FwcGxldC1kZXNjPg0KICA8amZ4OmphdmFmeC1kZXNjICB3aWR0aD0iODAwIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjYwMCIgbWFpbi1jbGFzcz0ic2ltcGxlX3JlbGF1bmNoamZ4LlNpbXBsZV9yZUxhdW5jaEpGWCIgIG5hbWU9IlNpbXBsZV9yZUxhdW5jaEpGWF8xXzAwMiIgLz4NCiAgPHVwZGF0ZSBjaGVjaz0iYWx3YXlzIi8+DQo8L2pubHA+DQo='
            },
            {
                javafx : '2.2+'
            },
            {

            }
        );

    } 


    function launchit(){
    count=count+1;

    addElement(count);
    dtjava.addOnloadCallback(javafxEmbed);
    hidepreviousElement(count-1);
    }



function addElement(cc) {

  var ni = document.getElementById('ccc');  
  var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
  var divIdName = 'javafx-app-placeholder'+cc;
  newdiv.setAttribute('id',divIdName);
  ni.appendChild(newdiv);
}

function hidepreviousElement(cc){
var ni = document.getElementById('javafx-app-placeholder'+cc);  
ni.style.display = 'none';
}

</script>

</head><body>
<h2>__</h2>


  <a href='#' onclick="launchit();">start JFX</a><br><hr><br>


  <br>

  <!-- Applet will be inserted here -->
  <div id='ccc'><div id='javafx-app-placeholder1'></div></div>

</body></html>
```

I hope that will be helpful to somebody and save his/her time ..

good luck ,'.